# Per Cell Calculation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, pixel

I have a population density raster data, but I'm trying to calculate the density per pixel? how do i go about this?

working with ArcGIS

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by pixel?

Comment: @The_Parser pixels of a raster are the individual cells. i hope that's clear

Comment: Yes I guessed as much, see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your title that you mean **people per raster cell**. You need to multiply your population density with the size of your raster cell (take care to use the same units!). The steps are ...

1. Calculate your raster cell area. The information you need of each cells height and width and the units that these measures are in can be found in the layer properties of your population density raster.
2. Then use the [Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z7000000) to make the calculation.

This will produce a new raster where the values represent the number of people in each raster cell.

Comment: so i understand you correctly, i multiply the raster by the cell height and width. the new raster is my people per cell product

Comment: Yes, For example if you have a cell size that is 0,5 kilometers by 0,5 kilometers then you have an area of 0,25 kilometers squared for each raster pixel. Then if you multiply that by the densiy of people in the pixel, lets say 2000 people per kilometer squared you get the number of people living in that pixel. 0.25 * 2000 = 500. The important thing is that the units must be the same, km in this case. Also of course this is just an estimate, in reality the number will not be exactly correct.